# PHP: Cannot see upload directory

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been struggling for a few days trying to find out how come I cannot move a file(`move_uploaded_file`) from temp to the directory I have setup (`/img/uploads/photos`).

After alot of testing and head scratching, I decided to write into CakePHP's CakeLog whatever is happening in the upload function.

Although I have physically created :`/img/uploads/photos`, when I use `CakeLog::write('debug', 'Does directory exist?: '.json_encode(file_exists('/img/uploads/photos/')));` it logs `false`. Or `is_dir`, also returns `false`

Why is this happening... Can anyone help me out!

Comment: The permissions of the directory need to be such that the directory is writable by the user running the web server.

Comment: Also use absolute path when moving files from one directory to another. Use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the current working directory, then add the rest of the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you have made a directory `/img/uploads/photos/` ? It is probably inside the same dir as your other files, somewhere like `/var/www/yoursite/img/uploads/photos/` or something like that.

You can use some tricks like `$_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}`, as you can see over at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Yeah... I forgot about that. I had to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you when you say you have created the `/img/uploads/photos/` directory. That's an absolute path, counting from the **root of the machine**. It's more probable that you have created the folder in the web directory somewhere (such as `/var/www/img/uploads/photos/` or `/home/caboone/public_html/img/uploads/photos/`).

Answer (score 0):

The path `/img/...` means the path is relative to the disk root, i.e. it denotes the `img` directory in the very top level of your hard disk. I doubt that's where the directory is. Don't start the path with a `/` to make it relative to the file you're working in. File paths are not URLs!

Comment: There's no such thing as a "disk root". It's the root directory of the machine (or even more specific: of the operating system). Disks may be mounted *anywhere*  within the directory structure. I understand that you're trying to explain it in a newbie-friendly way, but it's highly inaccurate for POSIX systems.

Comment: Filesystem root then if you're nitpicky. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use absolute path when moving files from one directory to another.
   Use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the **absolute** current working directory, then add
   the rest of the path.
2. Set appropriate permission to the directory, as suggested by @Alex. use `chmod()` and
   set permission to 777 (ugo+w) [user+group+others world-writeable].